# Css code not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a project for a client who is creating a share tribe website which also incorporates bootstrap.
Here is the [link](http://217.199.187.71/pranavkasetti.co.uk/files/unlease/index.html). 
You can view the source code on this website to see the code.

I have tried on the website to alter the css so that I can change the height of the input field, however my code in the index file doesn't change anything.

Also how do I go about changing the header bar at the top from white to have a clear background?

Also, I tried altering the css in the customstyles.css , and by manually inserting the `height="10px"' using 'inline css' however both of these didn't work.

Please let me know how to change the css to make this possible. Here is a JSFiddle too, to make it clearer:

### [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5arm63h6/)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div style="display: table; margin: 0px auto">
                <div class="input-group">

                <input type="text" id="q" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Where are you going?" style="height: 10px">
                <span id="submit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-success">Submit</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Clear your cache? Sounds more like you have an issue with your editing tools than a coding related question.

Comment: Those links will likely change in the future. You should post relevant sections of code. Form your question as if it were part of a wiki-style learning commons.

Comment: Clearing my cache didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as heck using jQuery if you have the option

```
$('.class').css('height','110px');
```

For multiple characteristics:

```
var params = ['height','width','text-align'];
var values = ['1000px','100px','center'];
for (p in params) {
    $('#id').css(params[p], values[p])
}
```

Comment: be sure to include jquery in the top left drop-down.

Comment: DANG this styling is sticky. its going to take me a minute.

Comment: The best i seem to be able to do is remove the top and bottom padding. The height won't budge but interestingly the width will. http://jsfiddle.net/omikey/5arm63h6/7/

Comment: Thank you, I managed a quick fix by removing box-sizing:content-box. Would you know how to change the header bar to be transparent/clear?

Comment: Try changing opacity  to '.5'

Comment: This made the Logo and buttons go transparent too. I only want the background-color to be clear. (When I type in".header {
 background-color:clear;
 }" nothing happens, even though it changes to red when I input red.

Comment: Try background-color rgb(255,0,0,.5) I Think it is

Comment: I don't want a red background - I want only the header background to be clear. This makes the whole header transparent red, but also all of the header logos and text.

Answer (score 0):

Your `customstyles.css` is working good and its call on page,

**You just need to change in the class**

`.marketplace-lander input[type=text]` -> `padding`

parameter. **padding is creating problem** for you in some resolutions.